# using amazon ses on google app engine issues

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ses

Hie

I am using amazon simple email service to send email from google app engine for java using the code documented at:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SendingEmail.Formatted.html

and Getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.<clinit>(VersionInfoUtils.java:41)
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:31)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.<init>(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:129)
at vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode.sendSubscriptionMail1(CommonServiceCode.java:965)
at vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode.handleSakshumMailingListSubscription(CommonServiceCode.java:937)
at vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.SubscribeServiceImpl.doSubscribe(SubscribeServiceImpl.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
... 1 more
```

Vik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally hit a github https://github.com/radomirml/aws-sdk-for-gaej which address my problem by providing patched jars

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all the prerequestes required by the Amazon JAVA SDK?

> Requires Apache Commons (Codec, HTTP Client, and Logging) third-party
>   packages, which are included in the third-party directory of the SDK.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFctory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:184)
com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createThreadSafeClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:26)
com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:83)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:116)

Comment: any advise on this? i get this after adding jars from third party directory